# More concise way of making quadratically spaced sequence?

Tags: python, numpy, sequence

Here's the code that accomplishes what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
b1 = np.linspace(-1.5,1.5)
sign = (b1 > 0)*1 
sign[sign==0] = -1
b1 = b1**2 * sign
```

Now I'll have more numbers about 0 since that's where the interesting information in my plot shows up.

I don't feel like this is very concise and I'm convinced there's a better way to do this.

(I suppose I could make a function that does this and just call it + add on more futures like even making it cubic scaled, etc... But I just think there must be a better way that I don't know about)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a more concise version using `np.where`:

```
np.where(b1 > 0, b1**2, -b1**2)
```

There's also a `np.sign` function:

```
b1**2*np.sign(b1)
```